# Ruby: instantiate objects from files

Tags: ruby

Overview:

```
main.rb
items/
    one.rb
    two.rb
    three.rb
```

Every file in `items/` should have a human readable description (serialization is out), like so (but maybe a DSL would be better?):

```
class One < BaseItem
    name "Item one"
    def meth
        "something"
    end
```

`main.rb` should be able to instantiate all objects from the `items/` directory. How could this be accomplished? Not familiar with Ruby, I see the object model allows for some pretty cool things (those class hooks, etc), but I'm having trouble finding a way to solve this.

Any input way appreciated.

EDIT:

Shoot, I may have missed the gist of it - what I didn't mention was the stuff in the `items/` dir would be dynamic — treat items as plugins, I'd want `main.rb` to autodetect everything in that dir at runtime (possibly force a reload during execution). `main.rb` has no prior knowledge of the objects in there, it just knows what methods to expect from them.

I've looked at building DSLs, considering defining (in `main.rb`) a `spawn` function that takes a block. A sample file in `items/` would look something like:

```
spawn do
    name "Item name"
    def foo
        "!"
    end
end
```

And the innards of `spawn` would create a new object of the base type and pass the block to `instance_eval`. That meant I'd need to have a method `name` to set the value, but incidentally, I also wanted the value to be accessible under `name`, so I had to go around it renaming the attr.

I've also tried the inherit route: make every item file contain a class that inherits from a `BaseItem` of sorts, and hook into it via `inherited` ... but that didn't work (the hook never fired, I've lost the code now).

EDIT2:

You could look at what [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) does with its formulas, that's very close to what I'd want - I just didn't have the ruby prowess to reverse engineer how it handles a formula.

Comment: You don't say what your research in solving this has lead you to, and why those things have failed to work for you. Tell us, so we don't end up playing 20 questions.

Answer (score 2):

It all boils down to requiring those files, and make sure that you implemented the functionality you want in them.

If you want a more specific response, you need to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on object persistence, but answer to your specific question is, that you have 2 good choices: One is YAML, and the other is Ruby itself: a DSL written by you or someone else, and specific to your business logic.

But I think that more general answer would require reviewing object persistance in Ruby more systematically. For example, ActiveRecord::Base descendants persists as database tables. There are other ways, I found eg. this http://stone.rubyforge.org/ by googling. This is my problem as well, I'm facing the same question as you in my work.

Comment: Couldn't use YAML because I need methods, not just attributes. Unless there's something about YAML I don't know.

Comment: @maligree: If it's just method names and simple arguments, YAML can handle it. If you need to specify method bodies in your file, than DSL it is.

Comment: Yeah, it's methods with bodies. But I actually like the idea of YAML being an IDL, thanks. Maybe sometime..

Comment: @maligree: That's a big fashion nowadays, converting XML based format into YAML based: Check HAML, SASS...

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for looks and smells a lot like a normal Ruby script.

```
class One < BaseItem
    name "Item one"
    def meth
        "something"
    end
```

We'd close the class definition with another `end` statement. `name "Item one"` would probably be done inside the `initialize` method, by setting an instance variable:

```
attr_reader :name
def initialize(name)
  @name = name
end
```

Typically we wouldn't call the folder "items", but instead it would be "lib", but otherwise what you are talking about is very normal and expected.

Instantiating all items in a folder is easily done by iterating over the folder's contents, requiring the files, and calling the `new` method for that item. You can figure out the name by mapping the filename to the class name, or by initializing an instance at the end of the file:

```
one = One.new("item one")
```

You could keep track of the items loaded in an array or hash, or just hardwire them in. It's up to you, since this is your code.

It sounds like you haven't tried writing any Ruby scripts, otherwise you would have found this out already. Normal Ruby programming books/documentation would have covered this. As is, the question is akin to premature optimization, and working with the language would have given you the answer.